# Angular-Spring Boot Application: 404 Error on Page Reload with Tomcat 10 Server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, server

**Issue**
I have an Angular frontend combined with a Spring Boot backend, running on a Tomcat 10 server. The routing within the application works flawlessly, but I encounter a persistent issue whenever I attempt to reload the page, leading to a 404 resource not found error.

**Here's the structure of my setup:**

Angular application located in webapps/ROOT
Spring Boot backend situated under webapps/spec
My application.yaml configuration:

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /spec
```

**Question:**
How can I resolve the issue of encountering a 404 resource not found error upon reloading the page in my Angular-Spring Boot application setup on a Tomcat 10 server? Additionally, how can I ensure that both frontend and backend functionalities are maintained intact even after implementing a solution for page reloads?

**Things I've Tried:**

Added `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />` in server.xml and configured rewrite.config with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html
```

This solution somewhat works as it allows page reloads without encountering a 404 error. However, it fails to load the backend, thus hindering functionalities like user login.